# NodeJS - how to send body in POST request?

Tags: javascript, typescript, http

I need to use `http` internal NodeJS library to make a `POST` request, how can i attach `body` object with this request? When I'm looking into `http.RequestOptions` I don't see any `data` or `body` property :/

```
import * as http from "http";

    const options2: http.RequestOptions = {
        hostname: 'www.google.com',
        port: 80,
        path: '/upload',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(null)
        },
      };
    
    http.request(options, (res: http.IncomingMessage) => {
        
    });
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: Which language are you actually using, and why are you asking about another?

Comment: @ScottHunter — That's typescript which matches the tag on the question.

Comment: @ScottHunter what are you talking about? I'm asking about TS and NodeJS

Comment: I'd recommend using node-fetch instead of http.request; it has a more modern API.

Comment: @Quentin nope, I can't use any internal libraries, I need this for npm package and I don't want install external dependency

Comment: I can use maybe even `https` or `http2` ;)

Answer (score 0):

[`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httprequestoptions-callback) returns an [`http.ClientRequest` object](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpclientrequest).

You need to call the `write` method on that and pass in your body data.